# R - Embedded inter-process communications (IPC) library

Tags: r, parallel-processing, inter-process-communicat

### Question

I'm looking for an **embedded IPC** framework because I want to achieve the following parallelism:

[image]

- I want to analyse **numerous sources of live data**
- I plan to use a **new process for each data source** to poll for updates
- This allows each **data source to be updated asynchronously** at its own polling interval, and without blocking updates for other data sources (important if a particular server is very slow)
- I need an IPC framework so I can **fetch the updates from each process** that is doing the polling to the process in which I'm doing analysis
- All R processes run on Windows ≥ XP **without admin privileges**, hence
  MPI as an IPC framework is not a possibility

To start, we can consider only
   the case where all processes run on a single machine (i.e. not over
   network). Does such a framework exist?

### Additional info

I've taken a look at R's [HPC page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html), which mentions MPI and [NetworkSpaces](http://nws-r.sourceforge.net/index.html) as possible frameworks that can handle inter-process communication. However, both require installations of external `.exe`s.

The HPC page also mentions [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html), but that package only seems to allow parallelisation via functions like `sfLapply` which does not allow for fine-enough control of the message passing.

Comment: This is a bit unclear still. Do you see one master computer spawning these threads to possibly other PCs? What does 'distribute solutions' mean? How are the answers combined - you say "fetch the updates" but maybe the threads can push them to a waiting service? Just a bit unclear. Maybe draw a diagram.

Comment: OK, will do - diagram coming soon. Let me get some sleep first.